# Custom ProgressBar with title and description

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

I'm trying to create a `ProgressBar` that includes also title and description

I have created an xml with a `LinearLayout`  that includes 2 `TextView` for title and description and a `ProgressBar`.

So I have tried to extend the default `ProgressBar` class with

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
    TextView title, description;
    public CustomProgressBar(Context con) {
        super(con);
        Activity a=(Activity)con;
        a.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressbarlayout);
        title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mybartitle);
        title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mybardescription);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Using `CustomProgressBar` in place of `ProgressBar`.
But It doesn't work correctly and every time I create a `CustomProgressBar` appears the layout that I have created with the intention to replace the default `ProgressBar` layout as a weird fullscreen activity.

Comment: have you tried playing with maxHeight and maxWidth attributes?

Comment: @Deepakkaku I haven't touched any attribute

Comment: try adding this to your layout. android:maxHeight="300dp"

Comment: Also, if you can provide your xml layout, it will be better. thanks

Comment: @Deepakkaku clearly the problem isn't the xml. Layout should inflate the original, matching its parent, if this doesn't happen and appears in fullscreen there is something wrong in the way I'm extending `ProgressBar` class.

Comment: If your custom `View` is to contain a `ProgressBar` and two `TextView`s, you don't want to extend `ProgressBar`, as it is not a `ViewGroup`, and can't hold other `View`s. Extend `LinearLayout` instead, so it can hold the aforementioned `View`s. Also, it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish with the `setContentView()` call in that constructor, but you really don't want to do that. That likely explains the "layout as a weird fullscreen activity", if I'm understanding that correctly.